# Show icon for dynamic grid page in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I am new to angularjs, I want to create grid with status icons.

Constant Code:

```
segment: {
type: 'segment',
name: 'segment',
contextKey: '',
innerLists: [],
foreignKey: 'segmentId',
title: 'name',
  metaData: [{
    key: 'id',
    text: 'ID'
  }, {
    key: 'name',
    text: 'Name'
  }, {
    key: 'segmentType',
    text: 'Segment Type',
    isSortable: false
  }, {
    key: 'status',
    text: 'Status',
    isSortable: false
  }]
 }
```

Controller Code:

```
function dataManipulator(data) {
//add property for the central display
data.forEach(function(entity) {
  if (entity.segment != null) {
    // status
    var active = entity.segment.active;
    if (active != null) {
      if (active == true)
        entity.status = 'Active';
      else if (active == false)
        entity.status = 'InActive';
    }

    entity.segmentType = angular.element('<img src="http://i.imgur.com/945LPEw.png" />');

  });
}
```

Problem: I am getting the following error

"Error: [$parse:isecdom] Referencing DOM nodes in Angular expressions is disallowed! Expression: getInnerField(item, col)"

I need solution for this issue, without using ng-grid. Appreciate your inputs.

Comment: Can you explain more about what you're trying to do?  By grid, do you just mean that you want a table?  And where are you trying to create this grid, from a controller or a directive?  And what is the purpose for trying to wrap the element?

Comment: Just I am trying to add new status column with respective icons in every row thats it. No I already have a table. I have created this table grid via constants. so I need to wrap the icon for the new table grid column.

Comment: Can you provide sample code, so that it will be understand.

Comment: Yes, it would be more helpful to see your code.  I'm not sure what you mean by constants so please show the controller and the view.

Comment: The error is in getInnerField(item, col).  I don't see this anywhere (and because it's a parse error) so I'm guessing it's in your view.  Can you please provide it?

Comment: I am not put any view code for this, bcoz its central include page (dynamic).

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean.  The error is a parse error on an expression that is trying to evaluate a function getInnerField.  Where is that happening if not in your view?  Here's the doc on isecdom errors: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/isecdom